# Node.js - OAuth through external HTTP-Proxy

Tags: node.js, oauth, proxy

i am new to Node.js. And want to create a small web application which should query twitter. I want to realize authentication via OAuth.

All traffic should be redirect through an external HTTP-Proxy. Does anybody know, how to configure the OAuth Module or if there is another OAuth module which supports proxies?

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Mikeal's Request: https://github.com/mikeal/request. You'll find an example of proxying and Twitter OAuth right on the READ.ME